# passing setState as props giving error not a function

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, react-props

I am trying to pass setState as a props, giving me error of not a function.
is it a good practice to pass setstate as props, if not what is the alternative

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import Form from "./form"

export default function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: "",
    phone: "",
    pincode: "",
    address: "",
    city: "",
    state: "",
    landmark: "",
    defaultAdd: Boolean
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form values={values} setValues={setValues}/>
    </div>
  );
}

import "./styles.css";


export default function Form({values, setValues}) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" value={values.name} onChange={(event) => setValues((prev) => ({ ...prev, name: event.target.value }))/>
      <input type="text" value={values.phone} onChange={(event) => setValues((prev) => ({ ...prev, phone: event.target.value }))/>
      <input type="text" value={values.pincode} onChange={(event) => setValues((prev) => ({ ...prev, pincode: event.target.value }))/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you don't know what are you doing, go and put some console logs. Print ```values``` and ```setValue```, then you will find out that setValues is undefined and values contains all the props. Props are the first argument of the component, here you defined 2. The correct way is ```function Form({values, setValues}){...}```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-bardeen-wx4g4n?file=/src/form.js

Comment: It works pretty well, what is the problem?